# Extracting part of a typescript API

Tags: typescript, lodash, definitelytyped

I've built a subset of `lodash` using the `lodash-cli` tool, and I'd like to extract the corresponding definitions from the `@types/lodash` typings.  It's easy enough to do this at the top level:

```
import type { LoDashStatic } from "lodash";

type Whitelist        = 'pick' | 'values' | 'padEnd';
type LoDashSubset     = Pick<LoDashStatic, Whitelist>;

const _: LoDashSubset = require("./lodash-subset");
```

But, it proves more problematic if we consider (explicit) chaining, because the various `ExpChain` (`CollectionChain`, `FunctionChain` etc) return types have properties that weren't on the whitelist.  So, the following will compile just fine:

```
type Whitelist        = 'pick' | 'chain';
...
_.chain({ a:[1,20], b:[2,10], c:[3,0] })
    .pick("a", "b")
    .sortBy(1)       // Uh oh! Not in Whitelist but the definition is still there.
    .value();
```

... but then I get a runtime failure when JS realises `sortBy` isn't there.

I've tried a few variations on mapped types but no luck, e.g.:

```
type Whitelist        = 'intersection' | 'chain';

type Restricted<T> =
    T extends {}
        ?   {
                [K in (keyof T) & Whitelist]:
                    T[K] extends (...args: infer Args) => infer U
                        ?   (...args: Args) => Restricted<U>
                        :   T[K]
            }
        :   T;

const _: Restricted<LoDashStatic> = require("./lodash-subset");

_.intersection([1,2,3], [2,3,4]);        // okay ...
_.chain([1,2,3]);                        // also okay ...
_.chain([1,2,3]).intersection([2,3,4]);  // COMPILE ERROR.  Ah, so close.
```

This fails to compile, with the error:

`TS2339: Property 'intersection' does not exist on type '{ chain: () => ...; }'.`

Note that this is more of a question about whether Typescript is up to the task than whether it should be done, let alone whether it should be done to Lodash!

Is such a slightly-deep slicing-and-dicing of an API possible within TS?

Comment: Unfortunately, I doubt you will get this to happen without copying the typings from lodash and filtering them (i.e., the brute force manual method). That `chain()` method has like 8 call signatures (overloads) most of which are generic; there's no simple `(...args: infer A) => infer R` mapping that will work in the face of overloads and generics the way you want.

Comment: I'm thinking the language would need mapped overloads (as in [microsoft/TypeScript#29732](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29732)) as well as higher kinded types (as in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213)) to even begin to do this programmatically.  You also can't modify the imported typings locally without forking them; declaration merging can sometimes be used to *add* things, but to remove things you can't do it without something like [microsoft/TypeScript#](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36146)).

Comment: If nobody comes up with a magical way to do this I will probably write up a "no, sorry" answer with an explanation.

Comment: **there's no simple (...args: infer A) => infer R mapping that will work in the face of overloads and generics the way you want**

This tracks with what I was seeing – testing the return type against `ExpChain<V>` to return a `Restricted<ExpChain<V>>` seems to match against the wrong generic signature (e.g. `PrimitiveChain<Unknown>` instead of `CollectionChain<number>`). A more in-depth explanation would be great if you get a chance, exploring the limits of TS.

Meanwhile, time for Plan C: filtering out declarations with the Magic Of Perl :-)